# Google Analytics: IP Filter does not exclude events

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, google-analytics-filters

I recently installed event tracking code on a web page to track a button click.
While the events are visible in my unfiltered view, they are also shown in views filtering my own ip address. Here are screenshots of the filtered event report:

[Filterd View of Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70BmR.png)

The report is exactly the same as the unfiltered view (which you have to belive me, since I can't upload more than two images yet). This should not happen, as I connect to the internet via a proxy with a fixed IP/ISP and tested the event tracking coming from this network. Here is the filter:

[IP Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd4am.png)

Hence, I would expect the event not to be shown in views excluding this IP address. Yet, the event report shows these exact events. I used the ISP as a second dimension to check, if these events were indeed triggered by myself (which is true).

These filters were installed before the event tracking and work correctly with page views. I double checked the IP filter is configured correctly.

**Update:**
If I take a look at the ISP report I see sessions listed under the ISP name of our company even though all IPs associated with this ISP should be excluded due to the IP filter. I double checked with our IT division that I'm not missing any IPs in my filter.

I also installed Tracking via the Google Tag Manager applying the same exclusion filter, yet the problem remains. I also created a second view with an IP filter like so `^123.456.789.1$|^123.456.789.9$`. Once more, the problem persists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about using filters in the google analytics website and is not programing related.

Comment: @DaImTo Why would filters and google analytics be off topic if there is a tag called `google-analytics-filters`?

Comment: I guess i could be wrong where you talking about the Google Analytics API if so please show your code so we can help you.   If you are talking about applying filters in the google analytics website then you would probably be better off asking on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as that inst really programming related and i recommend you post your code filter code there as well no one can help you with out it.

Comment: @DaImTo My question is indeed filter-reatled, not API-related. I see your reasoning here. If others agree with you, I'll repost this on webmasters.stackexchange.

Comment: @DalmTo - I had a similar situation and the issue was with the set up of the company VPN. When being on VPN and accessing our webiste I was routed through VPN well but through my home IP everywhere else. To check your external IP you can use something like tracert if you use Windows `tracert example.com` and see if that's what you expect. In my case the IP returned by tracert was from the VPN interface, which I was trying to filter out on GA. This wasn't working because GA seemed to filter based on the IP address taken from some HTTP headers (not 100% sure which ones though)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this with one of my own views, and it definitely covers events as well as page views, but I'm not sure why it would do one and not the other.

The only thing I can think of is that it's possible that the Predefined filter does the one and not the other. Failing that, try simply recreating the filter.

Here's my filter:

[image: Exclude Internal Traffic filter]

Comment: I'm using a custom filter exactly like yours.

Comment: Have you tried reapplying it? Do you have any other filters in place that might be interfering with it?

Comment: Yep, reapplying didn't change the outcome. Also, there are no other filters.